# NodeJS MongoDB return ten minutes old data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to return advertisement info that is ten minutes old. This is my current code:

```
    let adContacts = await AdvertisementContact.findOne({ad_id: advertisement._id,
        "created_at": {
            "$lte": moment().toDate(),
            "$gte": moment().subtract(10, 'minutes').toDate()
          }          
    });
```

This is what I get from console.log:

`moment().toDate()` 2019-02-26T19:26:51.885Z

`moment().subtract(10, 'minutes').toDate()`: 2019-02-26T19:16:51.885Z

Anyone knows how to make sure that when I login I could only see adContacts that are ten minutes old ? This doesnt show me ads even after ten minutes of waiting or longer.

Maybe I need to get date itself from the `adContacts` and then use it in `$gte` ?

Comment: Do you mean to have the `ad_id` part of the query? Are you trying to get ALL advertisements in the last 10 minutes or just a specific one?

Comment: @jakemingolla Only one. I go to the advertisement and then I need to show contacts of it after 10 minutes from when `AdvertisementContact` was created.

Comment: > Anyone knows how to make sure that when I login I could only see adContacts that are ten minutes old ? This doesnt show me ads even after ten minutes of waiting or longer.

The above query will only match advertisement contacts created in the last 10 minutes - is that what you want?

Comment: @jakemingolla Yes. The users have specific groups and one of the groups is that be able to see advertisement contacts after ten minutes after then it was posted. So I need to see info AFTER 10 minutes.

Comment: Okay, would `"$lte": moment().subtract(10, 'minutes').toDate()` be sufficient? You want to check if they have been created AT LEAST 10 minutes ago